# Estoy trabajando con archivos csv en python. Quiero crear una función para identificar el elemento que se repite más dentro del archivo

Tags: python, csv

Estoy trabajando con archivos csv de python. Mi código es para llevar el control de las series que una persona ha visto. Todo el código funciona bien y hace lo que yo quiero. Lo único que quiero añadir, es una función que permita calcular la plataforma de streaming que más se utiliza. La quiero poner después del último else para que lo indique al final de programa. Sé que tengo que buscar los datos del elemento[6] (que es el que contiene las plataformas) y hacer una función que identifique el elemento que se repite más. Intenté hacerlo varias veces y siempre obtuve error. ¿Me podrían dar una idea de como hacerlo?

```
import csv

with open('Temario B1.csv', 'r') as file:    
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
    
from tabulate import tabulate

print('---------------------')
print(data)
print('---------------------')

print(tabulate(data,headers = data[0]))

print('')




neto = True
while neto:
    
    k = input('¿Añadirá una serie? (Si,No): ').lower()
    if k == 'si':
        print('Menú:')
        print('1. Agregar datos')
        print('2. Mostrar tabla')
        print('3. Modificar datos')
        opcion = int(input('Escoja una opción:'))
    
    
        # Agregar datos
        if opcion == 1:
            datos = open('Temario B1.csv', 'a+')
            nombre = str(input('Ingrese el nombre de la serie: '))
            fecha = str(input('Ingrese la fecha que inicio a ver la serie (formato dd/mm/aaaa): '))
            estado = str(input('Ingrese el estado de la serie (En proceso, Finalizado, Nunca la terminaré de ver): '))
            duracion = str(input('Ingrese la duración de cada capítulo en minutos: '))
            cantidad = str(input('Ingrese la cantidad de capítulos vistos: '))
            plataforma = str(input('Ingrese la plataforma de streaming (Netflix, DisneyPlus,Primevideo, HBO): '))
            tiempoinvertido = str(int(duracion) * int(cantidad))
            archivar = datos.write('\n' + fecha + ',' + nombre + ',' + estado + ',' + duracion + ',' + cantidad + ',' + plataforma + ',' + tiempoinvertido)
            datos.close()
        
        # Mostrar tabla: Esta opción mostrará la tabla con las últimas modifaciones.
        # Hay que poner "no" cuando pregunte si quiere añadir serie para que aparezca la tabla actualizada.
        if opcion == 2:
            print(tabulate(data,headers = data[0])) 

        
        # Modificar estado
        if opcion == 3:
            print('Escoja la opción que desea modificar:')
            print('1. Estado')
            print('2. Capítulos vistos')
        
            opcion2 =int(input('¿Qué desea modificar?'))
        
            if opcion2 == 1:
            
                nombre_busqueda = input('Ingrese el nombre de la serie que desee cambiar el estado: ')
                estado_nuevo = input('Ingrese el estado actual de la serie: ')
            
                si_esta = False
                for elemento in data[1:]:
                    if elemento[1] == nombre_busqueda:
                        si_esta = True
                        elemento[2] = estado_nuevo
                    
                if(si_esta == False):
                    print('La serie ingresada no existe')
                        
                else:
                    print('Se cambio el estado')
                    contenido = 'Fecha inicio,Nombre Serie,Estado,Duracion capitulo,Capitulos vistos,Plataforma,Tiempo invertido'
                    for elemento in data[1:]:
                        contenido = contenido + '\n' + elemento[0] + ',' + elemento[1] + ',' + elemento[2] + ',' + elemento[3] + ',' + elemento[4] + ',' + elemento[5] + ',' + elemento[6]
                                
                    series = open('Temario B1.csv', 'w')
                    series.write(contenido)
                    series.close()
                
            if opcion2 == 2:
                nombre_busqueda1 = input('Ingrese el nombre de la serie a la que desea cambiar la cantidad de capítulos: ')
                caps_nuevo = input('Ingrese la cantidad actual de capítulos: ')
                duracion1 = input('Vuelva a ingresar la misma duracion que se registró anteriormente:')
                tiempoinvertido1 = str(int(duracion1) * int(caps_nuevo)) 
                si_esta1 = False
                for elemento in data[1:]:
                    if elemento[1] == nombre_busqueda1:
                        si_esta1 = True
                        elemento[4] = caps_nuevo
                        elemento[6] = tiempoinvertido1

                    
                if(si_esta1 == False):
                    print('La serie ingresada no existe')
                
                else:
                   print('Se cambio el estado')
                   contenido = 'Fecha inicio,Nombre Serie,Estado,Duracion capitulo,Capitulos vistos,Plataforma,Tiempo invertido'
                   for elemento in data[1:]:
                       contenido = contenido + '\n' + elemento[0] + ',' + elemento[1] + ',' + elemento[2] + ',' + elemento[3] + ',' + elemento[4] + ',' + elemento[5] + ',' + elemento[6]
                   
                   series = open('Temario B1.csv', 'w')
                   series.write(contenido)
                   series.close() 
                                
    else:
    
    
        neto = False
        print('Fin del programa.')
```

Comment: ¿Cómo es la función que intentaste para esto? ¿Qué error te dio?

Comment: Intenté meter el elemento[6] dentro de una lista. Media vez la tenía en la lista, intenté buscar la longitud de esta para luego separarla. Ahí fue donde me salió el error.